# Why am I getting "ERROR : request for member stringLength and name in something not a structure or union"?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, structure

I'm trying to implement a stack and its basic properties (push, pop, etc.) but I'm getting the error I mentioned in the title:

> ERROR : request for member stringLength and name in something not a structure or union

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct stackElement
{
    int stringLength;
    char *name;

} StackElement;

int Push(StackElement **stack);



int main()
{
    StackElement *stack = NULL;
    int index = 0;

    index = Push(&stack);


    printf("The top word of the stack is %s\n", stack[index].name);


    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}



int Push(StackElement **stack)
{
    char *c;
    int size = 0;
    int i = 0;

    *stack = malloc(sizeof(StackElement));

    printf("Please enter a word in the stack\n");
    scanf("%s",&c);

    size = sizeof(c)/sizeof(char);

    *stack[i].stringLength = size;// <---- ERROR

    *stack[i].name = c ;// <----- ERROR

    return i;

 }
```

Comment: `*stack.stringLength` throws the same error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an operator precedence issue.

`.` has higher precedence than `*`, so:

```
*stack[i].stringLength
```

Is the same as

```
*(stack[i].stringLength)
```

While you actually want

```
(*stack[i]).stringLength
```

Just add the brackets as I did in the last example and it should work.

Comment: Yeap that did the trick though now I found new problems. While the program runs now , after you put a word it crashes . I guess I have to make a new post.

Comment: The problem is here : `scanf("%s",&c);`. You must allocate memory before scanf. C is an uninitialized pointer. Do `c = malloc(20)` prior to the call to scanf. This allows only entry of strings shorter than 19 characters otherwise the buffer will overflow.

Comment: @user3385993 See Michael's comment above. Also note that `sizeof(c)` will always return the same size, regardless of what `c` points to, because `c` is a pointer, so the size of `c` is the size of a pointer - presumably you want to use something like [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) instead (and then forget about dividing by `sizeof(char)` - which is always 1 in anyway I believe).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will change my method a bit.